# Collect network computer details

Tags: c#, remote-access

i have written a program to collect details from remote computers in the network

```
private RemoteSysInformation.SystemInformation sysinfo;

if (sysinfo.Get(ipaddress, username, password) != RemoteSysInformation.SystemInformation.Status.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sysinfo.Get(ipaddress, username, password).ToString());
}        
else
{
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "BIOS Version", sysinfo.Bios }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "OS Name", sysinfo.OSName }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Version", sysinfo.OSVersion.description }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "OS Manufacturer", sysinfo.OSManufacturer }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "System Name", sysinfo.ComputerName }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Time Zone", sysinfo.Timezone.standardname }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Windows Directory", sysinfo.WindowsDirectory }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Total Physical Memory", SizePrettyPrint(sysinfo.TotalPhysicalMemory) }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Available Physical Memory", SizePrettyPrint(sysinfo.FreePhysicalMemory) }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Total Virtual Memory", SizePrettyPrint(sysinfo.TotalVirtualMemory) }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Available Virtual Memory", SizePrettyPrint(sysinfo.FreeVirtualMemory) }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Page File Space", SizePrettyPrint(sysinfo.PageFileSize) }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "System Manufacturer", sysinfo.SystemManufacturer }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "System Model", sysinfo.SystemModel }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "System Type", sysinfo.SystemType }));
    List.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Domain", sysinfo.Domain }));
}
```

but its keep giving the error **RPC service unavailable**
 PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

The error is `The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)`.

Comment: The error appears in your message box or somewhere in the console?

Comment: **messagebox** the list box is not getting filled

Comment: yes the metchine is up!!

Comment: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure service **Winmgmt** (Windows Management Instrumentation) is running on remote computer.

Comment: Can you try and run the application attached with blog post http://hemant-jangid.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-unique-machine.html? It also uses WMI to get the data from remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error message "RPC **server** unavailable" or "RPC **service** unavailable"?

- Is the remote machine up?
- Is the remote machine on the same LAN?
- Does the remote machine allow remote connections?
- Does the user you're specifying have the right permissions on the remote machine?
- Is there a firewall on the local and/or remote machines?
- Is there a firewall between the local and remote machines (maybe dropped RPC packets)?
- Are your DNS settings correct?
- What are the *option.* settings? For example, *options.EnablePrivileges*?